# Transition animation from hamburger to arrow icon on adding fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation

I have implemented master/detail flow and I would like to get transition animation from hamburger icon to arrow icon after adding fragment (the same animation as when opening navigation drawer).

I am using code like below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    toggle.syncState();

    //Add home page fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    HabitHomeFragment homePageFragment = new HabitHomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.habit_home, homePageFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();}
```

While adding details fragment:

```
public void showDetails() {
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.habit_home, habitDetailsFragment).addToBackStack("detail").commit();}
```

And toolbar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout> 
....
```

Currently after changing fragment the icon is just changed, without animation.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I haven't  found  any solution for this problem.

Comment: @Questioner, I've found two solutions. See answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some explanations first.

1. `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` uses special drawable class for hamburger-to-arrow icons and animation.
2. the class is `android.support.v7.graphics.drawable.DrawerArrowDrawable`
3. `DrawerArrowDrawable` implements animation with method `setProgress(float progress)`, where progress is from 0 (hamburger) to 1 (arrow).
4. ActionBarDrawerToggle uses `private void setPosition(float position)` that calls `DrawerArrowDrawable.setProgress()`
5. ActionBarDrawerToggle uses `public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)` to call private `setPosition()`
6. `ActionBarDrawerToggle` calls `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener()` in constructor with it's listener, that is used to toggle drawer.
7. `ActionBarDrawerToggle` keep track of actual `DrawerArrowDrawable` state. `Toolbar` and `ActionBar` do not track actual `DrawerArrowDrawable` state.

So, what you should do in activity. Option-A, use ActionBarDrawerToggle.

```
    // define a variable to track hamburger-arrow state
    protected boolean isHomeAsUp = false;

    protected DrawerLayout drawer;
    protected Toolbar toolbar;
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

    // I've implemented it in setContentView(), but you can implement it in onCreate()
    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        // overwrite Navigation OnClickListener that is set by ActionBarDrawerToggle
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else if (isHomeAsUp){
                    onBackPressed();
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // call this method for animation between hamburged and arrow
    protected void setHomeAsUp(boolean isHomeAsUp){
        if (this.isHomeAsUp != isHomeAsUp) {
            this.isHomeAsUp = isHomeAsUp;

            ValueAnimator anim = isHomeAsUp ? ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1) : ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, 0);
            anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                    toggle.onDrawerSlide(drawer, slideOffset);
                }
            });
            anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            // You can change this duration to more closely match that of the default animation.
            anim.setDuration(400);
            anim.start();
        }
    }
```

Or you can set a `DrawerArrowDrawable` as a navigation icon with         `toolbar.setNavigationIcon()` and animate it without `ActionBarDrawerToggle`
See Option-B: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42024138/1148784

Answer (score 4):

See my another answer for explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/42023946/1148784. This is option-B. code for `Activity` class. We do not use `ActionBarDrawerToggle` here.

```
    protected boolean isHomeAsUp = false;
    DrawerArrowDrawable homeDrawable;
    protected Toolbar toolbar;
    protected DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        homeDrawable = new DrawerArrowDrawable(toolbar.getContext());
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(homeDrawable);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else if (isHomeAsUp){
                    onBackPressed();
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void setHomeAsUp(boolean isHomeAsUp){
        if (this.isHomeAsUp != isHomeAsUp) {
            this.isHomeAsUp = isHomeAsUp;
            ValueAnimator anim = isHomeAsUp ? ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1) : ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, 0);
            anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                    homeDrawable.setProgress(slideOffset);
                }
            });
            anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            anim.setDuration(400);
            anim.start();
        }
    }
```